# System.InvalidCastException using XmlReader and XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml

Using XmlReader and XmlWriter.  I have an element that is being written to xml and then read back and re-written to a different file for a unit test.

The element is a bool.  So I convert to string object to write the first file. This works.

Then I convert to bool object to read it back in.  This works.

Last I go to re-write to the new file using the exact same XmlWriter method which converts it to a string. This does not work.

I get an error that says:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type *The name of my object*

Here is the Writer:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("myElement"))
{                      
   writer.WriteStartElement("myElement");
   writer.WriteCData(p.MyElement.ToString());
   writer.WriteEndElement();
```

}

Here is the Reader:

```
else if (reader.IsStartElement("myElement"))
{
   param.MyElement= System.Convert.ToBoolean(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
}
```

Comment: `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("myElement"))` I just facepalmed so hard I'm calling my lawyer.

Comment: You know `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("myElement")` will never be true, right?